# GARCH fit to the residuals of AR/ARMA mean equation previously fitted

Tags: r, arima, modeling, garch, volatility

Suppose I have an ARMA (p,q) (let it be ARMA (2,2)) fitted to my original returns series and have the residuals of said ARMA model extracted.

Next, it is my understanding that I need to fit a GARCH model to the *residuals* of the ARMA model.

Suppose I wanted to fit only a GARCH (1,1) to the residuals. In practice, for someone who's using `garchFit` function in R, this yields both a given GARCH (1,1) variance model and yet another ARMA (0,0) model.

My questions therefore are simple:

1. Does taking only the variance model specified from GARCH (1,1) fitting to the residuals and adding it to the first ARMA (2,2) model fitted to the returns series produces the actual time series?
2. Suppose I want to check if there's any heteroscedasticity left after doing all of this work, and I'm fitting a joint ARMA (2,2)+ GARCH (1,1) —— what should be specified in the `data` argument of the code, the residuals of ARMA (2,2) or the actual returns series?